# How to convert line to object with stroke and without fill in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, stroke

I want to convert a line element to an object in Inkscape and add a stroke to this object without fill. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase your stroke width to the wanted element width

Convert your stroke to a path

Give a new, narrower stroke to your new object and remove its fill. Ready.

See the following cartoon:

1 = the original stroke

2 = the wide stroke

3 = converted to path, the fill is removed, selected a narrow stroke

[image]

Comment: Which command do you use to go from 2 to 3?

Comment: @OleTange Several substeps: 3.1)Path  > Stroke to Path . Then In Fill & Stroke panel  3.2) Remove fill color  3.3) Select stroke color  3.4) Select a proper, narrow enough stroke width in the style tab.